# eBay Daily Deals API

Tags: ebay-api

I'd like to use the eBay API to get the deals available in the ["Deals & Special Offers"](http://www.ebay.co.uk/rpp/deals) (Daily Deals) section of the site. But I can't find any functions or function parameters that would allow me to do that. It seems I can only retrieve the data available on the main site, i.e. things I can find by using the "Shop by category" menu on the eBay home page.

Is there any way to get the Daily Deals using the API?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

please review
[eBay Deals: New Feed](http://www.helios825.org/eDD.php)

Comment: Thanks Jaydeep. One of the feeds described on that page seems to be what I'm looking for. For future reference - http://www.ebay.co.uk/rps/deals/DailyDeals-im.xml (it's a ~14M XML, you probably don't want to open it with your browser).

Comment: When looking at the URL in your answer, and then digging deeper by looking at http://deals.ebay.com/feeds/json, I noticed that the JSON is wrapped inside of (). Any idea why they might be doing that? Doesn't seem like that would be valid JSON...

Answer (score 0):

You should hit the official API, this is the new URL: http://api.epn.ebay.com/deals/v1/country/us/feed/json?feedType=json

Here's an example page of the output: http://www.fastsearchapps.com/deals